# Design a "family relationship" in MongoDB

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I have a `members` collection in MongoDB database where each document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "8801",
    "name" : "John Doe"
}
```

I need to store family relationships between members. That relationship is not directed.

Let's say John and Martha and Peter are family. When I query for John's family, I want Martha and Peter to be returned.

What is the best design for this? I have been thinking in a `families` collection where each document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "01",
    "members": ["8801", "0121", "7767"]
}
```

And query using `$in` operator against the `families.members` field.

What do you think? Am I losing NoSQL power when using this approach? Is there a better way?